# font doesnt work in IE and chrome is jagged

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I have problem with font, it doesn't work in IE 11 at all and in chrome is font jagged and doesn't look pretty.

Edit: font now works in IE, where looks absolutely perfect, but in chrome is still thin and jagged

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SourceSansProLight2;
  src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/2e5jfgm/DG0n1p902/sourcesanspro-light.eot');
  src:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2e5jfgm/DG0n1p902/sourcesanspro-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('http://static.tumblr.com/2e5jfgm/MJpn1p93b/sourcesanspro-light.svg') format('svg'),url('http://static.tumblr.com/2e5jfgm/9jnn1p911/sourcesanspro-light.woff') format('woff'),url('http://static.tumblr.com/2e5jfgm/mnvn1p90s/sourcesanspro-light.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
}

#container {
  font-family: SourceSansProLight2;
  font-size: 12pt;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wC5H/4/

Comment: oh sorry I forgot add code, thx for edit ;)

Comment: Jagged fonts in Chrome is simply because of their rendering. You can try some fixes with text shadows but it's just not perfect http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/

Comment: @Alex thank you, font still doesnt looks like in IE, but it is better now